# Как в PHPMyAdmin посмотреть триггеры в MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Как в PHPMyAdmin посмотреть триггеры в MySQL? Не могу найти этот раздел, есть раздел процедуры, но там написано "у вас нет прав для создания процедур" . Я свой триггер загрузил через SQL консоль в PHPMyAdmin, и он работает, но как его найти не знаю.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Заходите в БД и в верхней панели наводите курсор на "Ещё":

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Странно, у меня есть все разделы кроме "триггеры"  и "привилегии". Хм..

Comment: @semiromid, вполне вероятно, что у вас нет прав. Зайдите, как администратор.